# What did Terry Pratchett mean by "avec"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Terry Pratchett used in his disc world novels the word "avec" as a common food ingredient for french (in his books named "quirmian" or "Quirm" for the country) food.

Excerpt from "Snuff" by Terry Pratchett:

> Say what you like, the food in the Quirm Watch House canteen was pretty damn good, even if they did use a shade too much avec, thought Vimes; avec on *everything*.

I suspect that it means "garlic", deriving from an ellipsis on the french wording "avec ail" - "with garlic".

Is this correct? Thanks in advance & GNU Terry Pratchett :-)

Edit: Of course I'm aware that "avec" is the french word for "with", but that knowledge alone didn't help me here ;-)

Comment: In French, *avec* means *with*, so the implication is that the restaurant put too much *stuff* on a dish which is substantive enough on its own, and doesn't need garnish and decoration. Too many frills (for a steak-and-potatoes police officer). It's a play on the old trope that the French are fancy-pants and the English are solid salt-of-the-Earth. There's a lot of allusions to British culture and longstanding tropes in Pratchett. In fact, that (along with old Python sketches) is where we poor deprived Yanks get to learn about these things!

Comment: No, I think that it's just a play on stereotypical French restaurant menus, where dishes are often something-avec-something, avec of course being French for 'with'.

Comment: In part it's a play on the use of French by people who don't understand it.  It's not uncommon, eg, to go into a US medium-price restaurant and see some sort of beef dinner listed "with a side of *au jus*".  (In fact, I've seen cans of beef broth sold by restaurant supply outfits and labeled *au jus*.)  (And my wife and I still joke around about the time we were told of the merits of the "artesian" bread that a restaurant was serving.)

Comment: I got a similar impression that *avec* had a specific (if unspecified) flavour. English prejudice might suggest garlic but I'm sure that wasn't stated.

Comment: @DanBron The only problem here is that you will not see *avec* on a French menu, simply because, in descriptions, French does not use *avec* where English would use *with*. *The girl with black hair* is *la fille aux cheveux noirs*, and *the boy with the broken leg* - *le garçon à la jambe cassée*. Similarly *chicken in red wine* is *coq au vin*, and *steak in béarnaise* sauce is *steak au sauce béarnaise*. *Coffee with milk and chocolate sprinklings* would be *café au lait au chocolat*. On a French menu there is not likely to be an *avec* in sight anywhere.

Comment: @WS2: I don't believe the satire is directed at 'restaurants in France' so much as 'French{-style] restaurants abroad' which are notorious for flowery, poetical descriptions with plenty of *avec*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about use of a specific word in a humourous fantasy setting, which has little relationship to normal English. It might be askable on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DJClayworth This question is about a word found in english literature written by a native english speaker, and it asks if there is any common (if colloquial) understanding for that word in this context that may be obvious to native speakers but wouldn't appear in a dictionary. Also that word has no fictional or fantasy reference like e.g. the well known "flux capacitor".

Comment: This concerns an instantiation, a one-off witticism, not part of standard usage. I'd say it belongs on Literature.SE, under the _meaning_ tag.

Comment: @HotLicks I've never encountered "with a side of _au jus_"; in my experience it's always "with au jus sauce."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terry Pratchett often used wordplay.

The word "avec" is mistaken by an English-speaker to be an ingredient. The failure of the Anglophone to realise that avec is not an ingredient, but just means "with", is the joke here.

Other times, for example when Vimes asks for a bacon sandwich without any avec, he means he just wants a bacon sandwich, no mayonnaise, lettuce or other complications. In this case without any avec, (without any with), is at the same time a humorous turn of phrase, a possible failure to understand that avec is not an ingredient, and as Dan Bron says, a typically British dismissal of the fussiness of French food, even in a canteen.

Comment: Yes, the joke here reminds me of the old cartoon where a diner reading a menu says, "'Soup du jour'—my favorite kind!"

Comment: Well, or Vimes is thinks the restaurant is overly pretentious and that, for example,  "bacon avec eggs" is really going one step to far.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought of it as a take on the fashionable, but slightly pretentious culinary term, 'umami'. Can't remember the book's title, but Sir Terry wrote about hard times in Ankh Morpork when a chef served old boots in lieu of steak and instructed staff to add more 'avec'.

Answer (score -3):

I think it probably means any type of garnish,spice,seasoning,or side dish. Because in Ankh-Morpork a meal is the food put in front of you, they're probably not used to the idea of having, say, steak *with*(avec) mashed potatoes, or parsley, or bearnaise sauce. Even in more upper-class homes, they'd probably just serve the steak first and potatoes later. So when a Quirmian chef suggests putting something other than meat on the plate with the meat, it's seen as a strange, foreign idea.

Answer (score -4):

I think avec must be an actual condiment. In Pratchett's book, "Mrs Bradshaw's Handbook to Travelling Upon the Ankh-Morpork & Sto Plains Hygienic Railway" (p.55), the description of Globerry's Cafe says "Traditional and substantial Ankh-Morpork cooking for those missing a taste of home who want food without avec or garlic." If avec means "with" then you would get the construction "food without with" which makes no sense. Also, Quirm exports "fancy foods with Avec, wine, art, education, dodgy seafood produce." Once again, Avec stands alone as an item.

Comment: "food without with" making no sense is the point of the joke. It's a joke about people not understanding the meaning of words from foreign languages.

Comment: 'avec' doesn't mean 'with' in Pratchett's joke. It is a nominative. Read the explanations again.

Comment: Quirm exports "fancy foods with Avec, wine, art, education, dodgy seafood produce." Once again, Avec stands alone as an item.

Comment: I'm afraid you are just not getting the joke.